# Custom order for Views 3 output

Tags: drupal, view, sql-order-by

I have a related field in a view that contains either a ranking 1 - 4, or NULL if the related record doesn't exist.  I need the results to return in this order:  1,2,3,NULL,4 whereas now, it returns the data set in this order:  NULL, 1,2,3,4.

It seems like this would be a simple thing to do, using

```
ORDER BY FIELD(field, 1,2,3,NULL,4) in hook_views_alter_query.
```

I looked at the SQL output from the view and extracted:

```
ORDER BY 
 field_partner_name_users__field_data_field_partner_ranking.field_partner_ranking_value,
```

then put this in the hook:

```
$query->orderby[0]['field'] = 
 "field_partner_name_users__field_data_field_partner_ranking.field_partner_ranking_value";
```

But when I try to use this field in the `ORDER BY`, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_partner_name_users__field_data_field_partner_ranking.field_partner_ranking_value' in 'order clause'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, is there a comprehensive guide to Views 3 out there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try hook_veiws_query_alter in your custom module along with hook_views_api